# Class attributes as dictionary is not reseting on new instance in Python

Tags: python, oop

First example:

```
class StatsCourseBuilder():
    test = 0

novoA = StatsCourseBuilder()
novoA.test += 1
novoA.test += 1

novoB = StatsCourseBuilder()
print(novoB)
novoB.test += 1
```

Second example:

```
class StatsCourseBuilder():
    test = {'name' : 0}

novoA = StatsCourseBuilder()
novoA.test['name'] += 1
novoA.test['name'] += 1

novoB = StatsCourseBuilder()
print(novoB)
novoB.test['name'] += 1
```

Results:

1. First example: `1`
2. Second example: `3`

Why is this happening?
Is the fact that I have a dictionary as the value of my attribute impacting?

Python documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Comment: `novoA.test += 1` creates a new `int` object and assigns it to `novoA.test` (which is an **instance variable** that **shadows** the class variable).  On the other hand, `novoA.test['name'] += 1` **mutates the dictionary**. It doesn't create an instance variable. So the difference is that in the first case you don't mutate anything, but you assign to an instance variable, in the second case, you do mutate the dict, but don't assign to an instance variable

Comment: So, class attributes never get "reset"

Comment: but, in the second case, when i create a new instance, the dictionary is new too, no?

Comment: No. Not is isn't. It isn't in **neither case** when you create a new of your custom class. Creating a new instance of a custom class does **not create new instances of the class variables**. *you* assign to an *instance variable* here: `novoA.test += 1` which **shadows** the class variable. The class variable is still there, just that it is shadowed on the instance. so `novoA.test` will no longer reslove to `StatsCourseBuilder.test` You never change the obejct (the int object) that the class variable is referring to, nor do you mutate that object

Comment: Got it bro...
In the first example, for python to generate a new number (which will be the increment), it creates a new instance of the `int` class and then this will represent my new number, that is, a new instance of the variable.

Then in the second example, I never recreate the dictionary, I am always using the same instance of the dictionary and I am changing only the internal value.

Comment: Yes, so you *could* do `novoA.test = {"name": novoA.test['name'] + 1}` and the behavior would be the same in both cases.